# journal for Mac OSX 10.6.6

Tags: calendar

I want a journal / calendar. "Things" might be a possibility but expensive. Mainly I need to good calendar able to make large comments and use it as a reference journal.
Any suggestions (:

Comment: Things is a todo-list application with very limited "journaling" functionality. Please explain what you're looking for in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

[Journler](http://journler.com/) and [MacJournal](http://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/) come to mind.